# Invertible matrix equals to unitary matrix times positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and $T:V\to V$ be a invertible linear operator. Prove that there exists a unitary operator $U$ and a positive operator $P$ on $V$ such that $T=U\circ P$.

How may I prove this theorem? Or its equivalent theorem in matrix form?

Comment: See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition

Comment: Could anyone help? My teacher gives me a hint: consider $T^\ast$.

Comment: This follows rather directly from singular value decomposition, if you've seen that. Write $T=UDV^*=(UDU^*)(UV^*)$

Comment: Look up *polar decomposition* in any relevant literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by user1551 in the comments, this is the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition). Also, as noted by Aaron in the comments, it can be proven with the SVD.

Here is another approach. To get the unitary matrix we orthogonalize the columns of $T$ by multiplying with $(T^*T)^{-1/2}$:
$$T = \underbrace{\left(T (T^*T)^{-1/2}\right)}_{U}\underbrace{(T^*T)^{1/2}}_{P}.$$

Of course, $P:=(T^*T)^{1/2}$ is SPD since $T^*T$ is. To see that $U:=T (T^*T)^{-1/2}$ is unitary, we compute the angle between vectors after applying it, and see that it is the same as the angle before:
$$\langle T (T^*T)^{-1/2} u, T (T^*T)^{-1/2} v \rangle = \langle u, (T^*T)^{-1/2}T^*T (T^*T)^{-1/2} v \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle.$$

And we are done.

---

Also of interest numerically:

One can apply the dense unitary matrix $U$ to a vector $w$ without actually constructing it or doing any dense linear algebra, by

1. Applying $(T^*T)^{-1/2}w$ with a preconditioned rational Krylov method, or rational matrix function approximation method, then
2. Applying $T$ to the result.

All this requires is a good preconditioner for $T^*T$, which is often available (e.g., algebraic multigrid).